# Some CSS questions

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css

I just started developing a new website and I have some questions. You can see the some of the html/css here: http://web12.leankursus.dk/

But I do have some CSS questions:

1) Why does the a:hover only apply to "OM OS" and "KONSULENT" and not the other links.

2) Why is the black "TESTIMONIALS" so wide?

3) "FORSKNING NYHEDER BØGER FORESPOERGSEL" Do have a lot of white space above them. Do you know why?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Put everything like this:

```
#header #tag-cloud #community {
color: #A7A6A6;
}
```

before this:

```
#header #tag-cloud a:hover {
color: #F46446;
}
```

Your links then will have unique colour but all your links on hover will have the same color. Does it make sense?

2) Here's what makes testimonials so wide:

```
#header #testimonials {
width: 300px;
float: right;
}
```

3) Display your links as a block element:

```
#header #tag-cloud .tiny-text {
font-size: 0.6em;
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the id "testimonials" twice. Look into that. Not tested myself. id names must be unique to one element on a page.

EDIT: But, after just now looking closer, probably not the problem, but still needs fixing.